# Debugging - Power Calculator Functions and Plots

Tags: r, debugging, genetics

After several failed attempts at installing the CATS package (2013) and changing R versions, and what not, I decided to work with the source code from [here](http://www.popgen.dk/software/index.php/CATS)

I created a single R script with all the R functions from the package, I 
ran them, and then I had hopes this code would run to plot power in the example at the end of the following code :

```
super.cats<-function(RR,MAFmax=0.5,MAFmin=0.005,by=50,rep=1536,SNPs=1E6,ncases,ncontrols,ncases2,ncontrols2,alpha=0.05/SNPs,...){
  powerList.O<-c()
  powerList.J<-c()
  powerList.R<-c()
  powerList.F<-c()
  power.O<-rep(0,length(RR))
  power.F<-rep(0,length(RR))
  power.J<-rep(0,length(RR))
  power.R<-rep(0,length(RR))

  MAF<-exp(seq(log(MAFmin),log(MAFmax),by=(log(MAFmax)-log(MAFmin))/by))
  for(nmaf in 1:length(MAF)){
    for(tal in 1:length(RR)){
      if(power.F[tal]>0.995&power.R[tal]>0.995){
        power.O[tal]<-1
        power.R[tal]<-1
        power.J[tal]<-1
        power.F[tal]<-1
        break
      }
      temp<-cats(risk=RR[tal],freq=MAF[nmaf],ncases=ncases,ncontrols=ncontrols,ncases2=ncases2,ncontrols2=ncontrols2,alpha=alpha,pimarkers=rep/SNPs,...)
      power.O[tal]<-temp$P.one.study
      power.J[tal]<-temp$P.joint
      power.R[tal]<-temp$P.rep.study
      power.F[tal]<-temp$P.first.stage

    }
    powerList.O<-cbind(powerList.O,power.O)
    powerList.J<-cbind(powerList.J,power.J)
    powerList.R<-cbind(powerList.R,power.R)
    powerList.F<-cbind(powerList.F,power.F)

    cat(nmaf," ")
  }
  cat("\n")

  obs<-list(powerList.O=powerList.O,powerList.J=powerList.J,powerList.R=powerList.R,powerList.F=powerList.F,RR=RR,MAF=MAF,ncases=ncases,ncontrols=ncontrols,ncases2=ncases2,ncontrols2=ncontrols2,rep=rep,curve=F)

  class(obs)<-"supercats"
  return(obs)
}


##############################

if(FALSE){
  #heat plot
  rr<-seq(1,2,by=0.025)
  c<-super.cats(rr,by=length(rr),ncases=765,ncontrols=1274,ncases2=100,ncontrols2=100,alpha=0.001,prevalence=0.01);
  plot(c,main="power",file=NULL)


  #curves
  rr<-seq(1,3,by=0.05)
  maf<-c(0.01,0.05,0.2,0.5)
  c2<-curve.cats(rr,maf,ncases=765,ncontrols=1274,ncases2=100,ncontrols2=100,alpha=0.001,prevalence=0.01);
  plot(c2,main="power2",ylab="Power",xlab="RR",file=NULL,col=1:4)


}


####

"cats" <-
  function (freq=0.5,freq2=-1,ncases=500,ncontrols=500,ncases2=500,ncontrols2=500,risk=1.5,risk2=-1,pisamples=-1,prevalence=0.1,prevalence2=-1,additive=0,recessive=0,dominant=0,multiplicative=1,alpha=0.0000001,pimarkers=0.00316)
  { model<-c(additive,recessive,dominant,multiplicative)

  if(sum(model==1)!=1)
    stop("chose only one model. e.i. one model must be 1 the others 0")
  if(sum(model==0)!=3)
    stop("chose only one model. e.i. one model must be 1 the others 0")


  if(freq<0|freq>1)
    stop("freq must be between 0 and 1")
  if((freq2<0|freq2>1)&freq2!=-1)
    stop("freq2 must be between 0 and 1 (or undefined as -1)")
  if((pisamples<0|pisamples>1)&pisamples!=-1)
    stop("pisamples must be between 0 and 1")
  if((prevalence2<0|prevalence2>1)&prevalence2!=-1)
    stop("prevalence2 must be between 0 and 1 (or undefined as -1)")
  if(alpha<0|alpha>1)
    stop("alpha must be between 0 and 1")
  if(prevalence<0|prevalence>1)
    stop("prevalence must be between 0 and 1")
  if(pimarkers<0|pimarkers>1)
    stop("pimarkers must be between 0 and 1")
  if(ncases!=as.integer(ncases)|ncases<0)
    stop("ncases must be a positive integer")
  if(ncases2!=as.integer(ncases2)|ncases2<0)
    stop("ncases2 must be a positive integer")
  if(ncontrols!=as.integer(ncontrols)|ncontrols<0)
    stop("ncontrols must be a positive integer")
  if(ncontrols2!=as.integer(ncontrols2)|ncontrols2<0)
    stop("ncontrols2 must be a positive integer")
  if(risk<0)
    stop("risk must be positive")
  if(risk2<0&risk2!=-1)
    stop("risk2 must be positive(or undefined as -1)")



  res<-.Call("cats",
             as.double(freq),as.double(freq2),as.integer(ncases),as.integer(ncontrols),
             as.integer(ncases2),as.integer(ncontrols2),as.double(risk),as.double(risk2),
             as.double(pisamples),as.double(prevalence),as.double(prevalence2),
             as.integer(additive),as.integer(recessive),as.integer(dominant),
             as.integer(multiplicative),as.double(alpha),as.double(pimarkers))



  options<-cbind(freq,freq2,ncases=ncases,ncontrols=ncontrols,ncases2=ncases2,ncontrols2=ncontrols2,risk,risk2,pisamples,prevalence,prevalence2,additive,recessive,dominant,multiplicative,alpha,pimarkers)

  result<-list(P.one.study=res[1,1],P.first.stage=res[2,1],P.rep.study=res[3,1],P.joint.min=res[4,1],P.joint=res[5,1],pi=res[6,1],T.one.study=res[7,1],T.first.stage=res[8,1],T.second.stage.rep=res[9,1],T.second.stage.joint=res[10,1],E.Disease.freq.cases1=res[11,1],E.Disease.freq.controls1=res[12,1],E.Disease.freq.cases2=res[13,1],E.Disease.freq.controls2=res[14,1],options=options)
  class(result)<-"CATS"
  return(result)
  }

curve.cats<-function(RR,MAF,rep=1536,SNPs=1E6,ncases,ncontrols,ncases2,ncontrols2,alpha=0.05/SNPs,...){
  powerList.O<-c()
  powerList.J<-c()
  powerList.R<-c()
  powerList.F<-c()
  power.O<-rep(0,length(RR))
  power.F<-rep(0,length(RR))
  power.J<-rep(0,length(RR))
  power.R<-rep(0,length(RR))
  for(nmaf in 1:length(MAF)){
    for(tal in 1:length(RR)){
      if(power.F[tal]>0.995&power.R[tal]>0.995){
        power.O[tal]<-1
        power.R[tal]<-1
        power.J[tal]<-1
        power.F[tal]<-1
        break
      }
      tempo<-cats(risk=RR[tal],freq=MAF[nmaf],ncases=ncases,ncontrols=ncontrols,ncases2=ncases2,ncontrols2=ncontrols2,alpha=alpha,pimarkers=rep/SNPs,...)
      power.O[tal]<-tempo$Pone.study
      power.J[tal]<-tempo$Pjoint
      power.R[tal]<-tempo$Prep.study
      power.F[tal]<-tempo$Pfirst.stage
    }
    powerList.O<-cbind(powerList.O,power.O)
    powerList.J<-cbind(powerList.J,power.J)
    powerList.R<-cbind(powerList.R,power.R)
    powerList.F<-cbind(powerList.F,power.F)
    cat(nmaf," ")
  }
  cat("\n")

  obs<-list(powerList.O=powerList.O,powerList.J=powerList.J,powerList.R=powerList.R,powerList.F=powerList.F,RR=RR,MAF=MAF,ncases=ncases,ncontrols=ncontrols,ncases2=ncases2,ncontrols2=ncontrols2,rep=rep,curve=T)

  class(obs)<-"supercats"
  return(obs)
}


lines.cats<-function(x,type="Replication",col=NULL,lty=2,...){
  if(type=="Joint")
    power<-x$powerList.J
  else if(type=="One")
    power<-x$powerList.O
  else if(type=="Replication")
    power<-x$powerList.R
  else if(type=="First")
    power<-x$powerList.F

  if(x$curve){
    if(is.null(col))
      col=1:length(x$MAF)
    for(nmaf in 1:length(x$MAF))
      lines(x$RR,power[,nmaf],col=col[nmaf],lwd=2,lty=lty)

  }
  else
    cat("only for curves \n")
}

rr <- seq(1,2,by=0.05)
maf <- c(0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5)
c2 <- curve.cats(rr,maf,ncases=600,ncontrols=600,ncases2=600,ncontrols2=600, alpha=0.000001,prevalence=0.01);

plot(c2,type="One",main="power2",ylab="Power",xlab="RR",file=NULL,col=1:4)
lines.cats(c2,type="Replication",lty=3)
lines.cats(c2,type="Joint",lty=2)
lines.cats(c2,type="First",lty=4)
legend("left",c("One stage","Joint","Relication","First Stage"),lty=1:4,bty="n")


###


lines.cats<-function(x,type="Replication",col=NULL,lty=2,...){
  if(type=="Joint")
    power<-x$powerList.J
  else if(type=="One")
    power<-x$powerList.O
  else if(type=="Replication")
    power<-x$powerList.R
  else if(type=="First")
    power<-x$powerList.F

  if(x$curve){
    if(is.null(col))
      col=1:length(x$MAF)
    for(nmaf in 1:length(x$MAF))
      lines(x$RR,power[,nmaf],col=col[nmaf],lwd=2,lty=lty)

  }
  else
    cat("only for curves \n")
}


####


plot.supercats<-function(x,type="Joint",file="power.pdf",col=NULL,main=paste("POWER N=",x$ncases,":",x$ncontrols,",",x$ncases2,":",x$ncontrols2," rep=",x$rep,sep=""),...){
  if(type=="Joint")
    power<-x$powerList.J
  else if(type=="One")
    power<-x$powerList.O
  else if(type=="Replication")
    power<-x$powerList.R
  else if(type=="First")
    power<-x$powerList.F


  if(!is.null(file))
    pdf(file)
  #curve
  if(x$curve){
    if(is.null(col))
      col=1:length(x$MAF)
    plot(x$RR,power[,1],ylim=c(0,1),main=main,col="transparent",...)
    for(nmaf in 1:length(x$MAF)){
      lines(x$RR,power[,nmaf],col=col[nmaf],lwd=2)
    }
    legend(min(x$RR),1,paste("MAF=",x$MAF),col=col,lwd=2,bty="n")
  }
  else{
    #image
    if(is.null(col))
      col=heat.colors(80)

    image(x$RR,x$MAF,power,col=col,main=main,log="y",ylim=c(0.005,.5),ylab="MAF",xlab="RR",...) 
    legend("topright",paste(1:10*10,"%"),fill=col[1:10*8],bty="n")

  }
  if(!is.null(file))
    dev.off()
}


####
.onLoad=function(libname, pkgname)
{
  library.dynam("CATS", pkgname, libname)
}
.onUnload=function(libpath)
{
  library.dynam.unload("CATS", libpath)
}



####

"summary.CATS" <-
  function(object, ...){
    if (!inherits(object, "CATS"))
      stop("Not an object of class CATS!")
    cat("Options \n")
    ob<-t(object$options)
    colnames(ob)<-"chosen" 
    print(ob)

    cat("Recommended thresholds:")
    print(structure(list("One stage Design"=object$T.one.study,"Stage 1 Threshold"=object$T.first.stage,"Replication Threshold"=object$T.second.stage.rep,"Joint Analysis Threshold"=object$T.second.stage.joint),class="power.htest"))

    cat("Eobjectpected disesase allele frequencies")
    print(structure(list("Cases in stage 1"=object$E.Disease.freq.cases1,"Controls in stage 1 "=object$E.Disease.freq.controls1,"Cases in stage 2"=object$E.Disease.freq.cases2,"Controls in stage 2"=object$E.Disease.freq.controls2),class="power.htest"))

    cat("Expected Power is:")
    print(structure(list("For a one-stage study" = signif(object$P.one.study,
                                                          3), "For first stage in two-stage study" = signif(object$P.first.stage,
                                                                                                            3), "For second stage in replication analysis" = signif(object$P.rep.study,
                                                                                                                                                                    3), "For second stage in a joint analysis" = signif(object$P.joint,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        3), pi = signif(object$pi, 3)), class = "power.htest"))
  }


###


"print.CATS" <-
  function(x, ...){
    if(!inherits(x,"CATS"))
      stop("Not an object of class CATS!")
    cat("Expected Power is;\n")
    print(structure(list("For a one-stage study"=signif(x$P.one.study,3),"For first stage in two-stage study"=signif(x$P.first.stage,3),"For second stage in replication analysis"=signif(x$P.rep.study,3),"For second stage in a joint analysis"=signif(x$P.joint,3),"pi"=signif(x$pi,3)),class="power.htest"))
  }

###

"cats" <-
  function (freq=0.5,freq2=-1,ncases=500,ncontrols=500,ncases2=500,ncontrols2=500,risk=1.5,risk2=-1,pisamples=-1,prevalence=0.1,prevalence2=-1,additive=0,recessive=0,dominant=0,multiplicative=1,alpha=0.0000001,pimarkers=0.00316)
  {


    model<-c(additive,recessive,dominant,multiplicative)

    if(sum(model==1)!=1)
      stop("chose only one model. e.i. one model must be 1 the others 0")
    if(sum(model==0)!=3)
      stop("chose only one model. e.i. one model must be 1 the others 0")


    if(freq<0|freq>1)
      stop("freq must be between 0 and 1")
    if((freq2<0|freq2>1)&freq2!=-1)
      stop("freq2 must be between 0 and 1 (or undefined as -1)")
    if((pisamples<0|pisamples>1)&pisamples!=-1)
      stop("pisamples must be between 0 and 1")
    if((prevalence2<0|prevalence2>1)&prevalence2!=-1)
      stop("prevalence2 must be between 0 and 1 (or undefined as -1)")
    if(alpha<0|alpha>1)
      stop("alpha must be between 0 and 1")
    if(prevalence<0|prevalence>1)
      stop("prevalence must be between 0 and 1")
    if(pimarkers<0|pimarkers>1)
      stop("pimarkers must be between 0 and 1")
    if(ncases!=as.integer(ncases)|ncases<0)
      stop("ncases must be a positive integer")
    if(ncases2!=as.integer(ncases2)|ncases2<0)
      stop("ncases2 must be a positive integer")
    if(ncontrols!=as.integer(ncontrols)|ncontrols<0)
      stop("ncontrols must be a positive integer")
    if(ncontrols2!=as.integer(ncontrols2)|ncontrols2<0)
      stop("ncontrols2 must be a positive integer")
    if(risk<0)
      stop("risk must be positive")
    if(risk2<0&risk2!=-1)
      stop("risk2 must be positive(or undefined as -1)")



    res<-.Call("cats",
               as.double(freq),as.double(freq2),as.integer(ncases),as.integer(ncontrols),
               as.integer(ncases2),as.integer(ncontrols2),as.double(risk),as.double(risk2),
               as.double(pisamples),as.double(prevalence),as.double(prevalence2),
               as.integer(additive),as.integer(recessive),as.integer(dominant),
               as.integer(multiplicative),as.double(alpha),as.double(pimarkers),PACKAGE="CATS")



    options<-cbind(freq,freq2,ncases=ncases,ncontrols=ncontrols,ncases2=ncases2,ncontrols2=ncontrols2,risk,risk2,pisamples,prevalence,prevalence2,additive,recessive,dominant,multiplicative,alpha,pimarkers)

    result<-list(P.one.study=res[1,1],P.first.stage=res[2,1],P.rep.study=res[3,1],P.joint.min=res[4,1],P.joint=res[5,1],pi=res[6,1],T.one.study=res[7,1],T.first.stage=res[8,1],T.second.stage.rep=res[9,1],T.second.stage.joint=res[10,1],E.Disease.freq.cases1=res[11,1],E.Disease.freq.controls1=res[12,1],E.Disease.freq.cases2=res[13,1],E.Disease.freq.controls2=res[14,1],options=options)
    class(result)<-"CATS"
    return(result)
  }

#### EXAMPLE 
rr<-seq(1,2,by=0.05)
maf<-c(0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5)
c2<-curve.cats(rr,maf,ncases=600,ncontrols=600,ncases2=600,
               ncontrols2=600,alpha=0.000001,prevalence=0.01)

plot(c2,type="One",main="power2",ylab="Power",xlab="RR",file=NULL,col=1:4)
lines.cats(c2,type="Replication",lty=3)
lines.cats(c2,type="Joint",lty=2)
lines.cats(c2,type="First",lty=4)
legend("left",c("One stage","Joint","Relication","First Stage"),lty=1:4,bty="n")
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in .Call("cats", as.double(freq), as.double(freq2), as.integer(ncases),  :    "cats" not available for .Call() for package "CATS" Called from: cats(risk = RR[tal], freq = MAF[nmaf], ncases = ncases, ncontrols = ncontrols, 
    ncases2 = ncases2, ncontrols2 = ncontrols2, alpha = alpha, 
    pimarkers = rep/SNPs, ...)
```

I have tried to tinker with the code, but the more I change it, the more errors appear. At this point, I would appreciate any kind of help.

Update on what I get when installing the package from R:

```
install.packages("CATS_1.02.tar.gz") 
Warning in install.packages : package ‘CATS_1.02.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1) 
library(CATS) Error in library(CATS) : there is no package called ‘CATS’
```

Update: Error when installing from command line using R CMD INSTALL CATS_1.02.tar.gz :

```
adris-imac:Desktop gwallace$ R CMD INSTALL CATS_1.02.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘CATS’ ...

** libs clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c CATS.c -o CATS.o In file included from CATS.c:4: ./cats.h:196:27: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]    if (z > LOWER_TAIL_ONE && !upper || z > UPPER_TAIL_ZERO)
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~ ~~ ./cats.h:196:27: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence
      this warning    if (z > LOWER_TAIL_ONE && !upper || z > UPPER_TAIL_ZERO)
                          ^
       (                           ) CATS.c:86:7: error: non-void function 'cats' should return a value
      [-Wreturn-type]
      return ;
      ^ CATS.c:106:7: error: non-void function 'cats' should return a value
      [-Wreturn-type]
      return ;
      ^ CATS.c:133:7: error: non-void function 'cats' should return a value
      [-Wreturn-type]
      return ;
      ^ 1 warning and 3 errors generated. make: *** [CATS.o] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘CATS’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/CATS’ adris-imac:Desktop gwallace$
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear the code is breaking on:

```
  res<-.Call("cats",
             as.double(freq),as.double(freq2),as.integer(ncases),as.integer(ncontrols),
             as.integer(ncases2),as.integer(ncontrols2),as.double(risk),as.double(risk2),
             as.double(pisamples),as.double(prevalence),as.double(prevalence2),
             as.integer(additive),as.integer(recessive),as.integer(dominant),
             as.integer(multiplicative),as.double(alpha),as.double(pimarkers))
```

`.Call` is used to call external C/C++ code:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/CallExternal.html

Without this code the R script will not work.

Also I tested installation of the package, and it seems to install fine:

```
> install.packages("CATS_1.02.tar.gz")
> library(CATS)
> R.version
platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          4.1
year           2017
month          06
day            30
svn rev        72865
language       R
version.string R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
nickname       Single Candle
> CATS::cats()
$P.one.study
[1] 0.961869

$P.first.stage
[1] 0.9806984

$P.rep.study
[1] 0.8297875

$P.joint.min
[1] 0.9999998

$P.joint
[1] 0.9529604

$pi
[1] 0.5

$T.one.study
[1] 5.326724

$T.first.stage
[1] 2.951729

$T.second.stage.rep
[1] 4.000192

$T.second.stage.joint
[1] 5.30794

$E.Disease.freq.cases1
[1] 0.6

$E.Disease.freq.controls1
[1] 0.4888889

$E.Disease.freq.cases2
[1] 0.6

$E.Disease.freq.controls2
[1] 0.4888889

$options
     freq freq2 ncases ncontrols ncases2 ncontrols2 risk risk2 pisamples prevalence prevalence2 additive recessive dominant multiplicative alpha pimarkers
[1,]  0.5    -1    500       500     500        500  1.5    -1        -1        0.1          -1        0         0        0              1 1e-07   0.00316

attr(,"class")
[1] "CATS"
```

## UPDATE

Based on latest clang error maybe try:

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="CFLAGS=-Wno-return-type CXXFLAGS=-Wno-return-type" CATS_1.02.tar.gz
```

## UPDATE 2

Also try to add the following to `~/.R/Makevars`:

```
CFLAGS=-Wno-return-type
CXXFLAGS=-Wno-return-type
```

Then re-install package:

```
R CMD INSTALL --clean --preclean CATS_1.02.tar.gz
```

Comment: Vince, thank you for taking the time to take a look at this. I wonder what's impeding me from installing the package.  I have the Single Candle version installed with platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0

Comment: Is there any error when installing? If so, update the question with the error log.

Comment: Updated. I have reinstalled R and Rstudio, but I get the same warning and error.

Comment: Can you try the following on the commandline (not in R): `R CMD INSTALL CATS_1.02.tar.gz`.

Comment: Also, to confirm, did you download the `tar.gz`? R will not fetch this for you.

Comment: Vince, I did download it. I updated my question with the error I get when installing from commandline

Comment: I updated the answer to include something else to try.

Comment: Tried it, but it gave me the error...I wonder if it's just the platform. A coworker tried it in his mac, and the same thing happened.

Comment: Thanks for update. Maybe someone else with a Mac on SO will post some help.